# Close socket handle utility

Tags: windows, winapi, sockets

Hi I need a utility to close server socket handles open by the process, on windows. I cannot use tcpview as it does not close the server socket (ESTABLISHED state). Process explorer comes close with its handle list and "close handle" option, but it only gives the handle path (like \Device\Afd) and if application has open many such sockets I cannot tell which handle I would like to close. Any idea?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?  Closing handles out from under a process is potentially hazardous.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.windowsconfidential.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html);

> CurrPorts allows you to close unwanted TCP connections, kill the process that opened the ports

Comment: It has the same problem as tcpview. Cannot close server socket.